# Is it possible to use Flutter-shipped Dart SDK as SDK for AngularDart?

Tags: dart, flutter, angular-dart

I've recently downloaded Flutter SDK for Android Development, and I'd be curious to test a bit AngularDart SDK too.
Is it possible to use Flutter-shipped Dart SDK even for AngularDart development, or it's in some way specific and customized to run Flutter?
I have this doubt, because when running.

```
flutter doctor -v
```

As Dart SDK prints out:

```
Dart version 2.0.0-dev.35.flutter-290c576264
```

Do you think it would be better to install a separate Dart environment for web development, in order not to mix things up?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No, the Dart SDK shipped with Flutter was stripped of web related components to reduce download size and therefore can't be used for Angular development.

For web development you therefore need to install the regular Dart SDK.

It is possible to share code between Flutter and Web though by creating a package that does not explicitly depend on Flutter or Web and contains shared code like model classes, Redux classes, or similar)

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation!